# Java - Uploading a Byte Array to PHP

Tags: java, php, http, arrays

I'd like to send a simple GET request to a PHP page.

In Java, I do the following.

```
String encoded_bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
String url_encoded_bytes = URLEncoder.encode(encoded_bytes, "UTF-8");
```

In PHP, I do the following but the blob field comes out as NULL in MySQL, although the insert itself is successful.

```
$bytes = base64_decode(urldecode($_POST['map']));
$upload_map = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `Map` (`String`, `Blob`, `Int1`, `Int2`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");
$null = NULL;
$upload_map->bind_param('sbii', $string, $null, $int1, $int2);
$upload_map->send_long_data(2, $bytes);
$upload_map->execute();
```

How could I make one of the arguments a byte array that  I can then get back in PHP for uploading to a MySQL database?

Comment: I don't see any byte array in your code... but you could pass it in a GET request using Base64 encoding.

Comment: @shmosel, got it! I'll update the question with what I've done.

Comment: You shouldn't really be URL encoding over Base64. There's a standardized Base64 variation that's meant to be URL safe. In Java, just use `Base64.getUrlEncoder()`. I'm not sure what the corresponding function is in PHP.

Comment: @shmosel, I see! In PHP, it is just `base64_decode($string)`